# Universal Quantification of a Predicate P(x)

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Consider the following statement: Every number is less than its square. Write the statement “Every number is less that its square” symbolically by defining a predicate and using a quantifier.

Answer:

P(x) = x < x²

Thus ∀x P(x)

Have I written this answer correctly?

Comment: Your answer is correct, but I'd refrain from writing $P(x)=x<x^2$ and I'd write "let $P(x)$ be $x<x^2$" instead.

Comment: @GitGud Or $P=\{x: x<x^2\}$.